# how to build jar package with comment with maven

Tags: java, maven

let's say I have a method that was deprecated and want the user to know which method to use with comments top of the method signature. Like this:

```
/**
 * Deprecated, use OrderService.getOrderListByParams() instead
 * @param merchantId
 * @return orderList
 */
@Deprecated
public List<Map<String, Object>> getOrderList(long merchantId)
```

And the user for example could `Ctrl+Q` in IDEA to see the comment and know which substituted method to use.

How can I specific that in `pom.xml` and make maven to build the method info together with the code?

Comment: `mvn site` is used for documentation .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi You mean I should be the documentation separately with maven and transfer it to the maven server some how?

Comment: A "standard" jar contains compiled code (no comments), you probably want to create a javadoc jar (there's a [plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) for that)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you build a `.jar` file, it contains only the complied java byte code, and no sources or javadocs.

Sounds like you want to include sources in a `.jar` file. You can do it using [maven source plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/).